# My selenium code is unable to locate the buttons at times and does at another time why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Basically my issue is that i can't find my buttons at time and at others i can and i manually checked definetly not an iframe issue(even if it was it wouldn't work at times and not on other), so i thought it might be a page loading too slow and inconsistently, i set sleep() to 5 secs or such still not working.

My code:

```
def twoclicks(idoutter,idinner):
    outter = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id," + idoutter + ") and @value='...']")
    outter.click()
    sleep(10)
    driver.find_element_by_id(idinner).click()
    sleep(7)
```

how can i change it to click only when my button shows and wait otherwise for like 20 secs if not pressed .

Comment: Any time something doesn't behave consistently, it's very likely a timing issue. Adding waits, as Todor's answer shows, is the way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `sleep()`, it's really a bad practice to have harcoded sleep intervals. Change your element getters with WebDriverWait:

```
def twoclicks(idoutter,idinner):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)   # if you are going to use this interval somewhere else, define it in a higher-level scope
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id," + idoutter + ") and @value='...']"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, idinner))).click()
```

The [`WebDriverWait.until()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) waits for a condition to be fulfilled, and then returns the matched element, on which the `click()` method will be called. It will wait for up to 20 seconds - the argument in its constructor, checking the page for the condition every 500 milliseconds.

You'll have to add these imports to use this approach:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Happy *inducing*! ;)

Comment: If you are going to use the same wait time multiple times in the same code block, you should store the wait in a variable, e.g. `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)` and then you can `wait.until(...)` as many times as you want. The only time you wouldn't want to do this is when you want to wait for different times, e.g. 5s vs 20s or whatever.

Comment: Just to be clear, your answer was fine... good even. I think a good number of people either don't know or don't know how to do this so I like to suggest it when it makes sense so that it's more widely known. It also makes your code cleaner, etc. which is always a good thing too. :)